# nativescript image upload to s3 encoding issue

Tags: amazon-s3, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm having issues uploading an image from Nativescript to AWS, and I'm pretty sure it's a configuration issue.

select an image

```
    const context = imagepicker.create({
      mode: 'single' // use "multiple" for multiple selection
    });
    await context.authorize();
    const selection: Array<ImageAsset> = await context.present();
    const imageAsset = selection[0];
    const source: ImageSource = await new ImageSource().fromAsset(imageAsset);
    const fileLocation = imageAsset.android ? imageAsset.android : imageAsset.ios;
    const fileType = mime.extension(mime.lookup(fileLocation));
    const image = source.toBase64String(fileType);
    console.log(image);
```

image at this point is: `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAASwCAIAAACVUsChAAAAA3NCSVQI...`

image location at this point is: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20181106-150854.png`

```
const fileLocation = imageAsset.android ? imageAsset.android : imageAsset.ios;
const signedUrl = await this.getSignedUrl(fileLocation);
```

Backend Code to get signedURL

```
const getSignedUrlPromise = (operation, params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getSignedUrl(operation, params, (err, url) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(url);
    });
  });
}
  const params = { 
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, 
    Key: `abc123/456/3/${fileName}`,
    ContentType: contentType,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64'
  }
  const url = await getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params).catch(err => {
    console.log('error', JSON.stringify(err))
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(err)
    }
  });
  console.log('success', url);
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ url: url })
  }
```

signedUrl at this point is:

```
https://myproject.s3.amazonaws.com/abc123/456/3/Screenshot_20181106-150854.png?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&Content-Encoding=base64&Content-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=1555517358&Signature=yyyyyyyy&x-amz-security-token=long_token
```

Then, using the signedURL, i upload the image:

```
    const mimeType = mime.lookup(fileLocation);
    this.http.put(signedUrl, image, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': mimeType,
        'Content-Encoding': 'base64'
      }
    }).subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log('resp2', resp);
    });
  }
```

When I open the file, this is what I see
[image]

and the meta-data on the S3 object looks correct
[image]
When I download the file and open it in NP++, I see the base64 value.

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAASwCAIAAACVUsChAAAAA3NCSVQI...
```

I also cannot open the downloaded image
[image]

---

ATTEMPT 2

I saw where some people were using buffers, so I changed my `image` code to

```
const image = Buffer.from(source.toBase64String(fileType).replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''), 'base64');
```

which the image is still broken, and when I download and open the file using NP++ I see

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,7,128,0,0,4,176,8,2,0,0,0
```

Comment: instead fo htt0->put , I am using `s3.upload`, did you try that as well?

Comment: Since this is on the front-end I don't want to put credentials in the client code.